# GPUImage Green Screen

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I am trying to do a green screen effect using GPUImage.  The effect I am trying to achieve is to play a movie of curtains opening and replace the white part of the movie with the image.  This will display the curtains and then the curtains open to display the image.

I have the movie displaying correctly and the white part of the movie is as black but the image does not display when the curtains open.  What am I doing wrong?

```
NSURL *sampleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"CurtainsOpening" withExtension:@"m4v"];

GPUImageMovie *movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:sampleURL];

movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = YES;

NSLog(@"movie file = %@", movieFile);

GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter *filter = [[GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter alloc] init];
[(GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter *)filter setColorToReplaceRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0];
[(GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter *)filter setThresholdSensitivity:0.0]; //was 0.4

[movieFile addTarget:filter];

UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"curtains.jpg"];
NSLog(@"inputImage = %@", inputImage);
GPUImagePicture *overlayPicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];

NSLog(@"overlayPicture = %@", overlayPicture);

[overlayPicture processImage];
[overlayPicture addTarget:filter];
//[movieFile addTarget:overlayPicture];

GPUImageView *view0 = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[view0 setFillMode:kGPUImageFillModeStretch];

NSLog(@"view0 = %@", view0);
[filter addTarget:view0];

[self.view addSubview:view0];

[view0 bringSubviewToFront:self.view];

NSLog(@"frame = %f %f", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

[movieFile startProcessing];
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured out it out.  If anyone wants to know you need to make the `GPUImagePicture` variable an instance variable so the code does not remove the variable from memory when it exits the method.

Comment: Just an FYI, but if you would like to check out a comparison of the quality of a green screen filter vs an alpha channel approach then you might want to take a look at this: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post18_green_screen/